# Нейронная сеть на С++ умножение матриц разного размера

Tags: c++, нейронные-сети

> Возникла проблема хочу написать простую нейронную сеть на C++,  но
>   столкнулся с одной проблемой, нужно перемножить матрицы  разного
>   размера и записать результат в массив. В чем заключается проблема, как
>   их перемножить если они разного размера я пытался сделать это,  но
>   этот алгоритм работает только для матриц одинакового размера. В python
>   они перемножаются нормально,  в С++ не понимаю как это сделать. В
>   python в массиве выводятся такие данные: hiden_input: [0.5 0.1], в С++
>   hidenImput[ 0.25 0.25 0 0.5 -0.4 0 ] при входных параметрах vodka =
>   1.0, rain = 1.0, friend = 0.0. По сути ход решения правилный только в С++ в массив записывается только ход умножения,  а не конечный
>   результат потому, что 0.25 + 0.25 = 0.5 и 0.5 + (-0.4) = 0.1, а
>   конечный результат [0.5 0.1] не выводится. Может я вообще неправильно
>   все делаю ,  я не использовал сигмойд потому, что хочу сперва понять
>   принцип работы поэтому активационная функция простая.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct InputParameters {
    double vodka = 1.0;
    double rain = 1.0;
    double frend = 0.0;
};

int activationFunc(double x) {
    double value = 0.5;
    if (x >= value) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    InputParameters obj;
    const int row = 2;
    const int col = 3;
    int kt = 3;
    double matrix[1][3] = {obj.vodka, obj.rain, obj.frend};

    double wightsInputToHiden1[1][3] = {
        0.25, 0.25, 0};
    double wightsInputToHiden2[1][3] = {
        0.5, -0.4, 0.9};

    double wightsInputToHiden[2][3] = { 
       {wightsInputToHiden1[0][0], 
        wightsInputToHiden1[0][1], 
        wightsInputToHiden1[0][2]},

       {wightsInputToHiden2[0][0],
        wightsInputToHiden2[0][1], 
        wightsInputToHiden2[0][2]}};

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> hidenImput(row, std::vector<double> (col));
    std::cout << "[ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
            hidenImput[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < 1; ++k) {
                // ошибка здесь, но не знаю как исправить
                hidenImput[i][j] += matrix[k][j] * wightsInputToHiden[i][j];
            }
            std::cout << hidenImput[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "]" << "\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

// Аналогичный код на python здесь все работает нормально ((
import numpy
import numpy as np

vodka = 1.0
rain = 1.0
friend = 0.0


def activation_function(x):
    if x >= 0.5:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0


def predict(vodka, rain, friend):
    inputs = np.array([vodka, rain, friend])
    weights_input_to_hiden_1 = [0.25, 0.25, 0]
    weights_input_to_hiden_2 = [0.5, -0.4, 0.9]
    weights_input_to_hiden = np.array(
        [weights_input_to_hiden_1, weights_input_to_hiden_2])

    weights_hiden_to_output = np.array([-1, 1])

    hiden_input = np.dot(weights_input_to_hiden, inputs)
    print("hiden_input: " + str(hiden_input))

    hiden_output = np.array([activation_function(x) for x in hiden_input])

    print("hiden_output: " + str(hiden_output))

    output = np.dot(weights_hiden_to_output, hiden_output)
    print("output: " + str(output))
    return activation_function(output) == 1


print("result:" + str(predict(vodka, rain, friend)))
```

Comment: а причем тут нейронная сеть?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что  При умножении матрицы на вектор-столбец (массив), число столбцов в матрице должно совпадать с числом строк в векторе-столбце, что у вас и наблюдается. Так что тут нет никаких матриц разного размера, а вы умножаете матрицу на массив, потому что двумерный массив с одной строкой, это и есть одномерный массив. В C++ для получения массива_столбца, нужно чтобы количество столбцов было ровно одно, а не количество строк. И к тому же, результатом умножения матрицы на вектор-столбец(массив) есть вектор-столбец(массив), а не вектор векторов, как у вас.

И, упрощая ваш код, можно написать:

```
InputParameters obj;
const int row = 2;
const int col = 3;  
double matrix[3][1] = 
          { obj.vodka, obj.rain, obj.frend };
double wightsInputToHiden[row][col] = 
          { {0.25, 0.25, 0 }, {0.5, -0.4, 0.9 } };
std::vector<double> hidenImput(row);
std::cout << "[ ";
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {             
        hidenImput[i] +=
             matrix[j][0] * wightsInputToHiden[i][j];           
    }   
    std::cout << hidenImput[i] << ' ';
}
std::cout << "]\n";
```

P.S.  цикл можно написать и так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
    hidenImput[i] = std::inner_product(
        wightsInputToHiden[i], 
        wightsInputToHiden[i] + col,
        matrix[0], double());           
    std::cout << hidenImput[i] << ' ';
}
```

Comment: ок попробую переписать

Comment: даа заработало)) спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Ширина матрицы весов должна совпадать с высотой вектора сигналов в результате будет вектор с количеством элементов как у матрицы весов,выходные и сигналы просто вектора-массивы,
в псевдокоде:

```
output=malloc(len(matrix))
output_activated=malloc(len(matrix))
for( int row =0;row<len(matrix);row++){
 output[row]=0.0
 output_activated[row]=0.0
 float tmp=0.0 
 for (int elem=0;elem<len(matrix[0]);elem++){
   tmp=matrix[row][elem]*signals[elem]
   output[row]=tmp
   output_activated[row]=sigmoida(tmp)
}
}
```